# $\pi$ Day puzzle one to twenty

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Create the numbers from 1 to 20

Using

- $\pi$
- Normal arithmetic operation $+ - * /$
- Square root $\surd$
- Exponential $(X^Y)$
- Negative() minus sign $-$
- Floor() function, express between  $[ x ]$

> $[ 3.0 ]$ and $[ 3.9 ] = 3$
>   $[-3.1 ]$ and $[-3.9 ] = -4$
>   
>   Forbidden

- Factorial
- Log
- More than four $\pi$

Doing the 20 numbers takes time but is easy. 
Now the challenge is to create all 20 numbers using the minimal number of $\pi$.

For example:

> 1 = $\pi$ /$\pi$ use two $\pi$ 
>   1 = [ $\surd\pi$  ] only need one $\pi$
>
> 2 = $[ \surd\pi ] + [ \surd\pi  ]$ use two $\pi$
>   2 = $-[ - \surd\pi ]$ use one $\pi$

I give you an initial target of 50 $\pi$ for all 20 numbers. But I know can be lower.

Comment: In the exponential can you use any number as exponent or just something else derived by π?

Comment: Are parentheses allowed?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore The exponential rule seems to use them.

Comment: @leol2 exponential just derived by $\pi$

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Parentheses allowed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to do it in 42 $\pi$s.

- 1: $\lfloor\sqrt\pi\rfloor$
- 2: $\sqrt{-\lfloor-\pi\rfloor}$
- 3: $\lfloor\pi\rfloor$
- 4: $-\lfloor-\pi\rfloor$
- 5: $\pi-\lfloor-\sqrt\pi\rfloor$
- 6: $\lfloor\pi\rfloor+\lfloor\pi\rfloor$
- 7: $\lfloor\pi\rfloor-\lfloor-\pi\rfloor$
- 8: $-\lfloor-\pi\rfloor-\lfloor-\pi\rfloor$
- 9: $\lfloor\pi\rfloor\times\lfloor\pi\rfloor$
- 10: $-\lfloor-\pi\times\pi\rfloor$
- 11: $\lfloor\lfloor-\lfloor-\pi\rfloor\rfloor^{\sqrt\pi}\rfloor$
- 12: $-\lfloor-\pi\rfloor\times\lfloor\pi\rfloor$
- 13: $\lfloor-\lfloor-\pi\rfloor\times\pi\rfloor$
- 14: $-\lfloor-\pi\times\pi\rfloor-\lfloor-\pi\rfloor$
- 15: $-\lfloor-\pi\rfloor\times\lfloor\pi\rfloor+\lfloor\pi\rfloor$
- 16: $\lfloor-\pi\rfloor\times\lfloor-\pi\rfloor$
- 17: $\lfloor-\lfloor-\pi\rfloor\times\pi\rfloor-\lfloor-\pi\rfloor$
- 18: $\sqrt{-\lfloor-\pi\rfloor}\times\lfloor\pi\rfloor\times\lfloor\pi\rfloor$
- 19: $-\lfloor-\sqrt{-\lfloor-\pi\rfloor}\times\pi\times\lfloor\pi\rfloor\rfloor$
- 20: $\lfloor\pi^\pi/\sqrt\pi\rfloor$

Comment: Ceiling function is not allowed.

Comment: wow 20 blow my mind. Please check "2" I will check the rest later. But i see you only use 2 $\pi$ for 11 and 20 and Ian use 3 on both so your count should be 41 unless you overspend in other place.

Comment: His 20 still uses 3.... And I swear this answer wasn't here as I was typing mine....

Comment: Nevermind you also use 3 on 20 didnt count the exponent

Comment: He beats me on 11.

Comment: THE ANSWER IS 42 !!! @JuanCarlosOropeza has found the ultimate question to Life, the Universe, and Everything!

Comment: I brute-forced with code and believe this to be optimal.

Comment: I was going to wait to give time for other try to solve it, But if @xnor say this is the best then congrats to GOTO 0.

Answer (score 10):

**I did it with 43.**

> 43 = $⌊\pi⌋^{⌊\pi⌋}-⌊-\pi⌋*-⌊-\pi⌋$

There might be a smaller number that this could be done with, but I got lazy after 13. I also don't use anything other than $\surd$,  $\pi$, $⌊$ $⌋$, $-$, $+$, $*$.

Exponents and parentheses are for suckers!
<sup>*(or maybe for people that get a lower score than me)*</sup>

> 1 = $⌊\surd\pi⌋$
>  2 = $-⌊-\surd\pi⌋$
>  3 = $⌊\pi⌋$
>  4 = $-⌊-\pi⌋$
>  5 = $⌊\pi⌋-⌊-\surd\pi⌋$
>  6 = $⌊\pi+\pi⌋$
>  7 = $⌊\pi⌋-⌊-\pi⌋$
>  8 = $-⌊-\pi⌋-⌊-\pi⌋$
>  9 = $⌊\pi * \pi⌋$
>  10 = $-⌊-\pi * \pi⌋$
>  11 = $-⌊-\pi * \pi⌋ + ⌊\surd\pi⌋$
>  12 = $⌊\pi * -⌊-\pi⌋⌋$
>  13 = $-⌊-\pi * -⌊-\pi⌋⌋$
>  14 = $-⌊-\surd\pi⌋ * ⌊⌊\pi⌋ - ⌊-\pi⌋⌋$
>  15 = $-⌊-\pi⌋ * -⌊-\pi⌋ - ⌊\surd\pi⌋$
>  16 = $-⌊-\pi⌋ * -⌊-\pi⌋$
>  17 = $-⌊-\pi⌋ * -⌊-\pi⌋ + ⌊\surd\pi⌋$
>  18 = $-⌊-\pi⌋ * -⌊-\pi⌋ - ⌊-\surd\pi⌋$
>  19 = $-⌊-\pi⌋ * -⌊-\pi⌋ + ⌊\pi⌋$
>  20 = $-⌊-\pi⌋ * -⌊-\pi⌋ - ⌊-\pi⌋$

Comment: ROFL on the hilarious observation

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a optimal solution, let's wait for rand'al thor and Gamow though, eheh!

Comment: maybe `parentheses are for suckers` but in 14 and 15 you use floor as parentheses :P

Comment: I sure do! But I don't use parentheses! ;)

Comment: Please Ian can you double check 15. I dont think is ok. I reduce it to −[−√π∗7] and that is 13

Comment: @Juan, You're right. I told you I got lazy after 13. :/ I corrected 15 still using 3 $\pi$s.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so I got **42**

Most of my answers are similar to Ian MacDonald's with the exception of 11 where I was a "sucker" and used an exponent...

> 1 = $ ⌊√π⌋ $
> 2 = $√(−⌊−π⌋)$
> 3 = $⌊π⌋$
> 4 = $−⌊−π⌋$
> 5 = $⌊π*√π⌋$
> 6 = $⌊π⌋+⌊π⌋$
> 7 = $⌊π⌋−⌊−π⌋$
> 8 = $−⌊−π⌋−⌊−π⌋$
> 9 = $⌊π⌋∗⌊π⌋$
> 10 = $−⌊−π∗π⌋$
> 11 = $⌊(-⌊-π⌋)^{√π}⌋$
> 12 = $-⌊π⌋∗⌊−π⌋$
> 13 = $−⌊−π∗−⌊−π⌋⌋$
> 14 = $−⌊−√π⌋∗⌊⌊π⌋−⌊−π⌋⌋$
> 15 = $⌊−π⌋∗⌊−π⌋−⌊√π⌋$
> 16 = $⌊−π⌋∗⌊−π⌋$
> 17 = $⌊−π⌋∗⌊−π⌋+⌊√π⌋$
> 18 = $⌊−π⌋∗⌊−π⌋−⌊−√π⌋$
> 19 = $⌊−π⌋∗⌊−π⌋+⌊π⌋$
> 20 = $⌊−π⌋∗⌊−π⌋−⌊−π⌋$

Comment: Yes, his answer was there. I was already checking it while your appear but nice try

Comment: It wasn't when I started. For whatever reason formatting takes time...

Comment: Btw Exponent doesnt suck. And I dont know why parentheses suck, but use $\lfloor x \rfloor$ to replace it doesnt.

Comment: We did it almost at the same time. My original answer was flawed, so I deleted it, fixed it, and undeleted it later just a few minutes before Warlord posted this one.

Comment: @GOTO I realized that after the fact, but at first I saw the "answered 3 hours ago" and I thought I was going crazy....

Comment: Your answer for 2 is wrong like @GOTO0, both should check Ian answer.

Comment: Your are right i was getting square root of 3, sorry.

Comment: THE ANSWER IS 42 !!! @JuanCarlosOropeza has found the ultimate question to Life, the Universe, and Everything!